# WebCrawler java numHops

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am trying to create a webCrawler that crawls .edu domains. One of the parameters that I give to my program is numHops. Is the number of hops just the number of /s in the url? 
For example, let us say that www.harvard.edu is in my seed file (numHops = 0).
Then I parse through www.harvard.edu for more anchor texts and I get www.harvard.edu/faculty and www.harvard.edu/about. So is the numHops = 1? And when I parse that webpage for more I get www.harvard.edu/facult/robinson (numHops = 3). Is there a flaw in this thought? Maybe when I crawl I can get a totally random website? I am not sure how to implement numHops basically.

Comment: Are you *creating*? Or are you *using someone else's program to do most of what I want*? Either way, a code sample would be nice so we have some idea of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the number of hops just the number of /s in the url?

No, that's not it. That would only be the case if all of the links on the main page drilled straight down into the site, adding one `/` with each link.  The number of hops is just the distance you are away from the main page that you started your crawl at.  In your example you start at `www.harvard.edu`, so all of the URLs you scrape from that page will be one hop away. All of the URLs you scrape from those pages will be two hops away from the starting page, and so on.  Those pages might be on the same site, one or many `/`s deep, or they might be on a different web site entirely, so the number of `/`s doesn't really tell you anything.